# How do I play an animation, wait, then fade out? (In unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, fade

Basically what the title asks. I want to play my animation, then after the animation is finished playing, I want there to be a small delay before it fades out of the scene in about 2 seconds. After it fades out, it should be disabled and reset.

Here's my code so far, but when I set unlocking to true, it does nothing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    public bool unlocking;
    Sprite unlockSprite;
    Sprite lockSprite;
    Color temp;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        unlocking = false;
        unlockSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("unlock");
        lockSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("lock");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (unlocking) {
            anim.Play("unlock");
            unlocking = false;
            sr.sprite = unlockSprite;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f));
            temp = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, 0f);
            sr.color = temp;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            sr.sprite = lockSprite;
            temp = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, 1f);
            sr.color = temp;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FadeTo(float aValue, float aTime)
    {
        float alpha = sr.color.a;
        for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / aTime)
        {
            Color newColor = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, Mathf.Lerp(alpha, aValue, t));
            sr.color = newColor;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
    anim.Play("unlock");
    unlocking = false;
    if (animInfo.normalizedTime >= 1)
    {
        anim.enabled = false;
        sr.sprite = unlockSprite;
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f));
        temp = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, 0f);
        sr.color = temp;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        sr.sprite = lockSprite;
        temp = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, 1f);
        sr.color = temp;
    }
```

Comment: OK, so you can tell if the animmation has finished playing by checking the animationstateinfo, and checking its playing what you thought and how far along that animation it is. Im not sure where you set unlocking to true... however,I would suggest none of your unlocking code wants to be like that in your update as it could just give you 0 fps for a while and sleep? ouch.. anyway, otherwise what you have seems plausable

Comment: Please don't call `Thread.Sleep` on the main thread.

Comment: @BugFinder First I would like to say that I'm very new to unity. I don't know what the animationstateinfo is, just the AnimatorStateInfo, and I don't know how to access that either. I've tried using a while statement with animation.isPlaying, but when I try to set the animation in the inspector, it won't add it (with the dot on the side and by dragging). Also, where am I supposed to put my unlock code? I set unlocking to true while the game is playing (in the inspector), I will add a trigger later.

Comment: for animationstateinfo, please take a look at the unity docs, they provide a lot of useful information.

Comment: @BugFinder I can't find it, can you provide a link for me please?

Comment: I typed "animationstateinfo" in google.  First hit https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html ...

Comment: @BugFinder Oh, you meant animaTOR not animaTION, that's what confused me. Can you clarify what you mean when the unlocking code ahouldn't be in my update? Where does it go? I updated my code (check the post above), and now all that happens when I run this section of code is that the unlock animation plays once and then resets. No fade, and the `sr.sprite = unlock` doesn't seem to be changing my sprite either. Also, if I can't  use `Thread.Sleep`, then how am I supposed to make a delay before the fade? Thanks for your help, I know I'm bad at understanding this stuff.

Comment: @ElanSK  your update routines need to be as fast as possible, the longer they are the crapper your frame rate, ergo, if you want to wait.... you sure as eggs dont need that in update.  Send it to a coroutine that runs in outside the update and can take its time

Answer (score 0):

One of ways to pull it off, is to make another coroutine, something like that:

```
IEnumerator UnlockSequence()
{
    while (animInfo.normalizedTime < 1.0f)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    anim.enabled = false;
    sr.sprite = unlockSprite;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    yield return StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f));
    // everything else
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works (mostly). for some reason, animInfo.normalizedTime is only returning 0, so I just used WaitForSeconds and put the exact time of the animation. The only problem I have now is that the line `sr.sprite = unlockSprite;` is not changing the sprite. I have made sure that unlockSprite is referencing the correct sprite, but all that happens is that after the animation plays, the sprite goes back to the default sprite (the one it had at the beginning of the scene) and I have no idea why. I've been searching for answers for hours and I can't find a solution.

Comment: As for animInfo.normalizedTime, you probably need to update it every time you check it. Or check for Animator.StateName or StateNameHash to see if it's current state is one used for unlock animation.


I've never tried to use the technique for changing sprites that you did. I usually have an Image object in scene, a child of Canvas, and I am changing Sprite on it, without using SpriteRenderer..

Comment: You should've posted it as another question BTW